# Using Firebase Analytics, how would I track/view users using light mode versus dark mode on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

Would this be done via a User Property? Are those only used to filter events, or can I go into User Properties and see a ratio of dark mode to light mode with like a pie chart? If so I can't figure out how to do that.